# Prestashop 1.6: CSS override doesn't work

Tags: css, themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

```
Prestashop 1.6.1.0
```

I'm trying to override the CSS file of `GDPRPro` module but to no avail.

Path to the CSS file in the module:

```
public_html/modules/gdprpro/views/css/basicLightbox.min.css
```

In `hookHeader` of GDPRPro module there is:

```
$this->context->controller->addCSS($this->getLocalPath() . '/views/css/basicLightbox.min.css');
```

I'm trying to override basicLightbox.min.css by putting it in my theme, paths that I tried (and I'm copying them from my IDE as I'm testing them right now):

```
public_html/themes/eprestashop/css/modules/gdprpro/views/css/basicLightbox.min.css
public_html/themes/eprestashop/css/modules/gdprpro/basicLightbox.min.css
public_html/themes/eprestashop/css/modules/gdprpro/css/basicLightbox.min.css
```

Module is enabled of course. The theme is correct. I even tried to clear cache, even if it shouldn't be necessary in my setup. Is there anything am I missing?

Comment: `public_html/themes/eprestashop/css/modules/gdprpro/views/css/basicLightbox.min.css` should be the correct one. It would be enough to create the file. Which is the result of `d($this->getLocalPath() . '/views/css/basicLightbox.min.css');`?

Comment: Maybe public_html/themes/eprestashop/css/modules/gdprpro/templates/views/css/basicLightbox.min.css ?